# We choose 3 numbers from a set. Find probability that the multiple is lower than 8192

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> We randomly select three numbers from the set $A = \{1, 2, 4, 8, .., 8192 \}$. Find the probability that the multiple of chosen numbers is not higher than $8192$.

My understanding: The given set consists of $14$ numbers, each of which is the result of multiplying the previous number by $2$. Thus the number of ways to choose three numbers from that set is $\dbinom{14}{3}={364}$

Now I need to find the number of favorable ways to choose 3 numbers so that $a \times b\times c \le 8192$. My question: Is there a way to do this elegantly? My only current solution would be to go manually through all the $ 1\times 2\times 4$ etc possiblities to see which expressions are less than $8192$. But that does not seem efficient at all especially if we had more numbers.

Comment: When you multiply powers of two you add exponents. Translate this into a problem of how many ways to sum three numbers to get a value less than or equal to thirteen. That may make the problem look more familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking 3 good numbers $2^a,2^b,2^c$ (wlog $0\leq a<b<c\leq 13$) from the given set is the same as asking $a+b+c\leq 13$. Clearly $3a+3\leq 13\implies a\leq 3$. So we have to solve it for $0\leq a\leq 3$.

> **Lemma:** Let $b_0= \lfloor {k-1\over 2}\rfloor$. If $1\leq b<c$ then $b+c\leq k$ has $b_0(k-b_0+1)$ solutions.
>
> *Proof:* Clearly $b\leq b_0$ and $c\leq k-b$, thus for fixed $b$ we have $k-2b$ choises for $c$. So we have $$\sum _{b=1}^{b_0} (k-2b) = b_0k-2\cdot {b_0(b_0-1)\over 2}=b_0(k-b_0+1) $$ solution.

So for $a=0,1,2,3$ we have $k=13,10,7,4$ and $b_0= 6,4,3,1$ so we have respectively $48,28,15$ and $4$ solutions.

So we have in total $95$ solutions. So $$P= {95 \over {14\choose 3}}={95 \over 364}\doteq 0.261 $$

Comment: Another question. If $b=a+x$ and $c=a+x+y$ where $x,y\geq 1$, why do we have $3a+x+y \leq 13$ instead of $3a+2x+y \leq 13$? Where does one of the $x$ dissapear?

Comment: Ive made a correction.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Is there a particular name for this lemma? I'd like to read up on it to make sure I understand how to apply it to other problems as well.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, it is not difficult to came up with it.